# Jest - Reinitialize module after env vars update

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Let's assume i have a file that is depending on some env vars:

### File.js

```
export const foo = process.env.FOO; // is undefined
```

Now I would like to update jests configuration, so that the env. var is set (even after the file is imported) :

### test.js

```
import {foo} from './file';

describe('getRootComponentProps', () => {
    const { env } = process;
    const originEnv = env;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        process.env = {
            ...originEnv,
            FOO: 'foo',
        };
        jest.resetModules(); // this does not help
        jest.resetModuleRegistry(); // this does not help
        jest.isolateModules(() => 
             jest.requireActual('./file'));
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        process.env = originEnv;
    });

    it('expect foo to be set', () => {
        expect(foo).toBe('foo'); // should be 'foo' and not undefined
    });
  });
```

I now I could technically set the required env vars and then lazy import the file.js but maybe there is another convinient approach

Comment: I guess this is just a trivial example, but I wouldn't unit test that file. Resetting the modules doesn't change the fact that you imported `foo` _before_ you reset them, if you do that you'll also have to `require` the new value.

Comment: Exactly this is just a trivial example for you to follow. The file in reality is a class with some more logic. So is there no other option apart from maybe do a lazy import or require again the value after i updated the env vars?

Comment: I think you should provide real examples.

Comment: This could be a real example though and should be enough to understand my underlying issue